# how to display uploaded image with FileField in django template

Tags: python, django, image, web, image-uploading

I'm currently learning `django` , I'm trying to create a simple upload site.
I figured out I should use `django` `FileField` for this purpose but I want to know how to display the images uploaded using this field on the index page using django template .
I know I can use the `ImageField` in my case but I'm trying to know if it is possible with `FileField` ?

Comment: Yes, sure, just use .url as usual. Example: product.image.url

Comment: when i do this it wont display the picture in the template and the link of the image says : Page not found .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="{{fileobj.url}}"/>
```